# How do I format a duration string to include two zeroes for a zero field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, format, duration

Using Rails 5.0.1 with Ruby 2.4.  I have a method that will display duration in milliseconds as a formatted string.

```
def time_as_str(time_in_ms)
  secs, ms    =   time_in_ms.divmod(1000)
  mins, secs  = secs.divmod(60)
  hours, mins = mins.divmod(60)
  s = "%d:%d:%d.%s" % [hours, mins, secs, ms.zero? ? "0" : ms.to_s.sub(/0*\z/,'')]
  if hours > 0
    s
  elsif mins > 0
    s[2..-1]
  else
    s[4..-1]
  end
end
```

I'm having a little trouble, though, since if either the minutes or seconds field is zero, the output is displayed as "0" instead of "00".  For example, if I call the function with

```
86400000
```

(that is the number of milliseconds in 24 hours), the output is

```
"24:0:0.0"
```

But I would like it to be

```
"24:00:00"
```

Similarly if the input is

```
1000
```

The output should just be

```
"1"
```

Since one thousand milliseconds equals one second.  How do I properly format my output to include two zeroes if necessary?

Comment: use %02d instead of %d, this will pad the resulting number to 2 digits

Comment: Thanks.  I replaced "%d:%d:%d.%s" with "%02d:%2d:%02d.%s" but now when i call my function with 150401, for example, the output is ":02:30.401".  It shoudl be "2:30.401".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it as follows:

```
def time_as_str(time_in_ms)
  secs, ms    =   time_in_ms.divmod(1000)
  mins, secs  = secs.divmod(60)
  hours, mins = mins.divmod(60)
  s = "%d:%02d:%02d%s" % [hours, mins, secs, ms.zero? ? "" : "."+ms.to_s.sub(/0*\z/,'')]
  (hours > 0 ? s : mins > 0 ? s[2..-1] : s[5..-1]).sub(/^0/,"")
end
```

Basically % will interpolate whatever you pass,`%d` means print as digit, `%02d` print as digit occupying at least 2 digits, pad on the left with 0 until 2 digits at least are present. Then you'll want `%s` to actually print an empty string in case no `ms` or `ms=0` and if not print a string of `ms` with a dot on the left side.

I think you should decide on what ms holds prior to `format/interpolate` the string so that then you don't need to call a ternary operator inside the `format` array.

Comment: Thanks.  The only hiccup here is if I plug-in 150401 I get back "02:30.401".  I would like to eliminate leading zeroes, so just have the answer be "2:30.401".  However, if the input were 120000, I'd want the output to be "2:00" as opposed to "2:0".  Does that make sense?  I don't quite know how to describe this succinctly.